# Getting unmanaged models

Tags: database, django, view

I seem to have a problem after creating an unmanaged model (syncdb):

```
class Client_jobs(models.Model):
    job_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'client_jobs'
        managed=False
```

in one of my def views, it calls the database view(Client_jobs)

```
def listjobs(request):
    # if user is authenticated
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
          jobsArr = Client_jobs.objects.get.all()
```

The page returned me an error of

(1146, "Table 'table1.client_jobs' doesn't exist")

I know I'm missing something but I can't figure out. How does django detect this unmanaged model? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as I know the db_table option will get precedence over the existing convention of app name_model name. If you set it explicitly you will have to prefix the application name yourself.
try client_jobs.client_jobs